# Problem coming in using vlookup formula in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeDaf.jpg) I want get value in CV of DA if CZ contains value of CR. Here we are matching CR username with CZ user id if its matching then i want to print data of DA in column CV. I am working in spreadsheet. I tried this work with vlookup, hlookup and vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP()` should work. Try-

```
=VLOOKUP(CR2,$CZ$2:$DA$5,2,0)
```

You can also use `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=XLOOKUP(CR2,$CZ$2:$CZ$5,$DA$2:$DA$5)
```

[image]

Comment: Its also not working sir. Where its completing the criteria there #REF! Error is coming. Where criteria is not completing there #N/A error is coming. XLOOKUP formula is not working in spreadsheet. I am using WPS Spreadsheet.

Comment: Which formula are you using?

Comment: Thankyou sir, its working now. Before some time i was using 3 in replacement of 2 in formula.

Comment: Sir i have some more questions can you help me?

Comment: UNIQUE formula is not working in spreadsheet. Can u tell me similar formula as UNIQUE.

Comment: @PawanKumar `UNIQUE()` is available to ***Excel365*** version. For older version you need to use combinations of few formulas. I would suggest to accept this answer (tick mark it) and ask a separate question.

Comment: Ok sir, i accept it. Then can you tell me combination of formula to find unique data in a single column. I have some different names in repeating in column A and i want to get only once repeated names in column B.

Comment: That would be possible only seeing your sample data. You can ask another question and give link here to me so that I can post answer to that question. This is how stack overflow works.

Comment: Thankyou sir, i found tha solution for it. Combination of formula is =INDEX($A$2:$A$15,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$15),0)) and its working sir.      I have one more question i have a time format like 00:00:00:00, i want to change in minutes this. 00(days in hours):00(hours):00(mins):00(seconds) i want to calculate it in minutes.

Comment: @PawanKumar if you have more questions, don't post them as comments, but as a question. Also, if you use WPS spreadsheet, don't tag Excel.